# what is my error in this code?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, null

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Dim myconn As MySqlConnection
    Dim mycommand As MySqlCommand
    Dim myadapter As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim mydata As DataTable
    Dim sql As String


    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        myconn = New MySqlConnection

        sql = "select * from inventory"

        myconn.ConnectionString = "server =localhost;" _
            & "user id=root;" _
            & "password=;" _
            & "database=testing"


        Try
            myconn.Open()

            mycommand.Connection = myconn
            mycommand.CommandText = sql

            myadapter.SelectCommand = mycommand
            myadapter.Fill(mydata)

            DataGridView1.DataSource = mydata


        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to database" & myerror.Message)
        Finally
            myconn.Close()
            myconn.Dispose()


        End Try
    End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: i got an error of "NULL REFERENCE exemption was unhandled"

Comment: Is it a compilation error or runtime error? Error code? Error message? Debug breakpoint? Expected behaviour? Actual behaviour? You need to be a bit more explicit than this if you want your question to stay open. SO users are very quick to react to poorly worded questions.

Comment: in which line you get this error ?

Comment: I'm sorry i'm a beginner, i can debug my program but when i click the button to view my data in datagrid it gives me an error "NULLexemption unhandled" and it point to the code "mycommand.connection = myconn" there's a red line under the myconn. please help me with this is my thesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to Create object using `New`

Just Add

```
mycommand = new MySqlCommand()
myadapter =new MySqlDataAdapter()
```

Like this

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Dim myconn As MySqlConnection
    Dim mycommand As MySqlCommand
    Dim myadapter As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim mydata As DataTable
    Dim sql As String


    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        myconn = New MySqlConnection()
        mycommand = new MySqlCommand()
        myadapter =new MySqlDataAdapter()
        sql = "select * from inventory"

        myconn.ConnectionString = "server =localhost;" _
            & "user id=root;" _
            & "password=;" _
            & "database=testing"


        Try
            myconn.Open()

            mycommand.Connection = myconn
            mycommand.CommandText = sql

            myadapter.SelectCommand = mycommand
            myadapter.Fill(mydata)

            DataGridView1.DataSource = mydata


        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to database" & myerror.Message)
        Finally
            myconn.Close()
            myconn.Dispose()


        End Try
    End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys, i just add "Dim myconn As MySqlConnection
    Dim mycommand As MySqlCommand
    Dim myadapter As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim mydata As DataTable
    Dim sql As String" again after the private sub

Comment: Is your problem fixed now?

Answer (score 0):

This is initialization  issue change your click event like this :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    myconn = New MySqlConnection

    sql = "select * from inventory"

    myconn.ConnectionString = "server =localhost;" _
        & "user id=root;" _
        & "password=;" _
        & "database=testing"


    Try
        myconn.Open()

        mycommand = New MySqlCommand(sql,myconn)
        myadapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(mycommand)
        myadapter.Fill(mydata)


        DataGridView1.DataSource = mydata


    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to database" & myerror.Message)
    Finally
        myconn.Close()
        myconn.Dispose()


    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes man,thanks to all of you.

Comment: if it's work for you please mark as answer for reference.